# Is there any C preprocessor as an independent program?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I know that **C** preprocessor exists as part of compiler. But I'm looking for an independent program. Is there any such tool?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's often called `cpp`. For example, on my Linux box:

```
CPP(1)                                GNU                               CPP(1)

NAME
       cpp - The C Preprocessor

SYNOPSIS
       cpp [-Dmacro[=defn]...] [-Umacro]
           [-Idir...] [-iquotedir...]
           [-Wwarn...]
           [-M|-MM] [-MG] [-MF filename]
           [-MP] [-MQ target...]
           [-MT target...]
           [-P] [-fno-working-directory]
           [-x language] [-std=standard]
           infile outfile
```

This particular one is part of [`gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/cpp/) and is available for a wide variety of platforms.

Answer (score 4):

[mcpp](http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/).

From the homepage:

> mcpp is a C/C++ preprocessor with the following features.
>
> - Implements all of C90, C99 and C++98 specifications.
> - Provides a validation suite to test C/C++ preprocessor's conformance and quality comprehensively. When this validation suite is applied, mcpp distinguishes itself among many existing preprocessors.
> - Has plentiful and on-target diagnostics to check all the preprocessing problems such as latent bug or lack of portability in source code.
> - Has #pragma directives to output debugging information.
> - Is portable and has been ported to many compiler-systems, including GCC and Visual C++, on UNIX-like systems and Windows.
> - Has various behavior modes.
> - Can be built either as a compiler-specific preprocessor to replace the resident preprocessor of a particular compiler system, or as a compiler-independent command, or >even as a subroutine called from some other main program.
> - Provides comprehensive documents both in Japanese and in English.
> - Is an open source software released under BSD-style-license.

Answer (score 4):

You can also have a look at [m4](http://mbreen.com/m4.html#toc5)

> What is m4?
>
> M4 can be called a “template language”, a “macro language” or a “preprocessor language”. The name “m4” also refers to the program which processes texts in this language: this “preprocessor” or “macro processor” takes as input an m4 template and sends this to the output, after acting on any embedded directives, called macros.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [filepp](http://www.cabaret.demon.co.uk/filepp/) for preprocessing files other than straight C.  It's a Perl module, so it's pretty portable.  It's handy in that you can use all the familiar idioms you are used to, and adds some useful features.

From the web site:

> Why filepp and not plain old cpp?
>
> cpp is designed specifically to
>   generate output for the C compiler.
>   Yes, you can use any file type with
>   it, but the output it creates includes
>   loads of blank lines and lines of the
>   style:
>
> # 1 "file.c"
>
> Obviously these lines are very useful
>   to the C-compiler, but no use in say
>   an HTML file. Also, as filepp is
>   written in Perl, it is 8-bit clean and
>   so works on any character set, not
>   just ASCII characters. filepp is also
>   customisable and hopefully more user
>   friendly than cpp.

Comment: Note that most compilers, such as GCC, have something like a -P switch which omits the generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

`cpp` is just one. It's a separated program called by `gcc` when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

It is a part of the package, and usually called `cpp` (C PreProcessor).

```
which cpp
# /usr/bin/cpp
man cpp
```